# Does the following C/C++ code invoke undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, c, variable-assignment, ternary-operator, undefined-behavior

```
int a = 2, b = 3, c = 4, d = 5;
a > 1 ? b : c = d;
```

One my friend told me that this invoked undefined behavior and I feel like the opposite. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Why does he think it would it give undefined behavior?

Comment: Pick a language. C/C++ is not a language.

Comment: Since it may behave differently in C and C++, so I will be happy to hear the details/differences between both languages.

Comment: @porker2008; Difference is that **C != C++**. Do not compare.

Comment: Using the term "C/C++" invoked undefined answers.

Comment: @hacck, thanks, I know what happened now. They are indeed very different languages.

Comment: @KerrekSB; I just want to know if the code will produce different result in two different languages. =)

Comment: @porker2008: Then why don't you say that in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If to write the operator like

```
( a > 1 ? b : c ) = d;
```

(because in this way it is parsed in C) then it is valid in C++ but will not be compiled in C because in C the operator returns rvalue.

If to remove the parentheses then in C++ it will be equivalent to

```
a > 1 ? b : ( c = d );
```

Thus the operator behaves differently in C and C++. In C record

```
a > 1 ? b : c = d;
```

is equivalent to

```
( a > 1 ? b : c ) = d;
```

and will not be compiled.

In C++ record

```
a > 1 ? b : c = d;
```

is equivalent tp

```
a > 1 ? b : ( c = d );
```

and will be compiled.

Moreover if to rewrite it in C++ in the same way as it is parsed in C

```
( a > 1 ? b : c ) = d;
```

then again it will be compiled because the operator in C++ returns lvalue.

Here is the definition of the operator in C

```
conditional-expression:
       logical-OR-expression
       logical-OR-expression ? expression : conditional-expression
```

and here is the definition of the operator in C++

```
conditional-expression:
       logical-or-expression
       logical-or-expression ? expression : assignment-expression
```

As you can see that apart from the semantic difference there is a difference in the grammar of the operator relative to the third expression.

Answer (score 1):

This code will not invoke undefined behavior but will produce some error in C as `a > 1 ? b : c = d;` will be evaluated as

```
(a > 1 ? b : c) = d;
```

`a > 1 ? b : c` will result in an rvalue which can't be a left operand of assignment operator `=`.

Comment: **Note**: the mentioned error only applies to [tag:C] (the code is valid [tag:C++]).